# error while using regular expression in angular 2 , Module parse failed : Octal literal in strict mode

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am having a regular expression in my environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {

passwordPolicy: "^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}.*$"

};
```

however i am getting an error as follows when i do an ng test

```
ERROR in ./src/environments/environment.ts
Module parse failed: Octal literal in strict mode (74:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     passwordPolicy: "^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}.*$"
| };
| 
 @ ./src/app/shared/services/config.service.ts 22:20-64
 @ ./src/app/shared/services/users.service.ts
 @ ./src/app/shared/services/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/users/users.component.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts
```

please help me 
thank you

Comment: can you try using Template literal (` `) instead of Double Quote(" ")?

Comment: tried with both single quotes and template literal but it doesnt work . same issue ..thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to double your backslashes.

```
"^(?!.*(.)\\1\\1)(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}.*$"
```

Otherwise it assumes you are trying to escape the 1 from your string.